# How to add fadeout and fade in effect in a java frame?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I tried something like this but it only works for fadeout

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    float op=(float) 1.000;
    while(op>=0.0)
    {
        setOpacity(op);
        op=(float) (op-0.000001);

    }
    dispose();
    new HomeScreen();
  tm.stop();
}
```

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.